# UITextView - How to prevent keyboard to be shown when using readonly TextView

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I am using a `UITextView` to show some text but I don't want the user to be able to edit it. I have tried setting the property `Editable` to false, but the keyboard still shows when I touch on the text.

Is there any other property I could set to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: This will also stop the scrolling, which is the prime feature of textView.

Answer (score 0):

You sure you set the property correctly? Or Is your textview nil? You should check it, if everything is OK,then

```
textview.editable = NO;
```

should work.

BTW, do not use`textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` because if your text is very long, you cannot scroll textview to show more

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the solution that "MarkHim" posted, or you can do this from the storyboard.

[image: Storyboard side panel]

Just check/uncheck the boxes that say "Editable" and "Selectable" in the "Behavior" section. By unchecking "Editable" the keyboard will no longer come up.